# Promise and subscribe

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-services

I have an Angular2 (ionic2) application. I have a function that request cities but I get an error that Property subscribe does not exists on `this.cityService.getAllCities()`.

cityPage.ts has a function like this:

```
getCities(){
    this.cityService.getAllCities()
          .subscribe(cityData => { this.cityList = cityData; },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('Complete!')
    );
}
```

my cityService.getAllCities() function looks like this:

```
getAllCities(){

    return new Promise (resolve => {
        this.storage.ready().then(() => {

            this.storage.get('authData').then(authData => {
              let hdr = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +
                authData.access_token });
              let opt = new RequestOptions({ headers: hdr });
                return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_GET_CITIES).map(res => <CityModel[]> res.json(), opt);
            }).catch(() => {
              //resolve(false);
            });

        });

    });

  }
```

**Edit**

Based on the comment I've changed my function like this:

```
getAllCities(){

    return Observable.create(resolve => {
        this.storage.ready().then(() => {

            this.storage.get('authData').then(authData => {
              let hdr = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +
                authData.access_token });

                console.log('access_token ' + authData.access_token);
              let opt = new RequestOptions({ headers: hdr });
                 return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_GET_CITIES,opt).map(res => <CityModel[]> res.json()).subscribe((result) => {
                  console.log(result);
                  resolve = result;
                });
            }).catch(() => {
              //resolve(false);
            });

        });

    });

  }
```

In my `console.log(result)` I receive data, but the data is never returned to my `getCities()` function. Also the `console.log('Complete!')` is not called.

Comment: Promise.Then... Use subscribe for Observer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason it is throwing an error, because `.subscribe` method does available on `Observable` to listen to, whenever it emits a data. Here from `getAllCities` method you're returning a `promise` you could apply `.then` function over it to get data returned from that `Promise`

```
getCities() {
  this.cityService.getAllCities()
    .then(
       cityData => { this.cityList = cityData; },
       err => console.log(err),
       () => console.log('Complete!')
  );
}
```

And also return promise from `getAllCities` method by calling `.toPromise()` method over `http.get()` Observable.

```
getAllCities(){

    return new Promise (resolve => {
        this.storage.ready().then(() => {

            this.storage.get('authData').then(authData => {
              let hdr = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +
                authData.access_token });
              let opt = new RequestOptions({ headers: hdr });
              //returned promise from here.
                return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_GET_CITIES)
                   .map(res => <CityModel[]> res.json(), opt)
                   .toPromise();
            }).catch(() => {
              //resolve(false);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The above gave me the solution, although I had to change some of the code. Instead of `return this.http.get` I had to do `resolve(this.http.get)`

Comment: @kwv84 `return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_GET_CITIES)
                   .map(res => <CityModel[]> res.json(), opt)
                   .toPromise()` should also do the trick

Comment: @PankajParkar same thing for me, have to add resolve(this.http.get)...and i olso keep the .`toPromise()`