# Angular: How to better handle nested API calls particularly if the latter is dependent on the result of the former

Tags: angular, observable, angular-httpclient

I am in this situation where i write my api calls in a nested format. Given the requirement that the api calls made latter is dependent on the result of the former, is there a better way to handle this? I particularly want to find an clean & elegant solution in terms of better organizing the calls so i can avoid the nesting

UPDATE:

here is the code that represent the real situation I want to handle better:

The api calls represent the sequence in which the actions/flow of the application should be. Is there a better way to handle the nested calls?

```
  dummyMethod(){
    activeModal.result.then((modalResult)=>{
      var payload = {
        id:modalResult.id,
        value:modalResult.value,
      }

      this.dataService.updateRelationship(payload)
      .subscribe(response =>{
        if(response.success){
          var payload:{
            otherId: response.someId,
            otherValue:response.someValue
          }
          this.dataService.doCleanup(payload)
          .subscribe(otherResponse => {
            if(otherResponse.success){
              var anotherPayload:{
                someOtherId: otherResponse.otherId,
                someOtherValue: otherResponse.otherValue,
              }
              this.dataService.fetchResults(anotherPayload)
              .subscribe(results => {
                // do something with results
              }, error => {
                // log error
              });
          }}, otherError => {
            // log error
          });
        }
      }, error => {
        // log error
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: the pyramid of doom ;) have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596557/9793532)

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: How is the `data` response used in each of the nested calls? Are they only used in the next API request or used by others down the chain as well? Also, it is an anti-pattern to have nested subscriptions. Instead that is what the `switchMap`/`concatMap`/`flatMap` operators help out with in RxJS.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I have updated the source code example to be a bit more clearer. and to represent the exact situation I would like to handle better.

Answer (score 4):

You'd usually pipe and flatMap (or any other operator that is appropriate for your use case):

```
this.http.get(url)
  .pipe(
    flatMap((data: any) => this.http.get(url + data.whatever)),
    flatMap((data: any) => /* ... */)
  )
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

For requests that don't rely on each other, you could use `zip`

```
zip(this.http.get('foo'), this.http.get('bar'))
  .subscribe(([foo, bar]) => ...)
```

Comment: I have updated the question with source code that represent my exact situation, can you please take a look and let know is there a better way to handle this? TIA.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `promise`, `async`, and `await`. I found this article that describes what you're trying to do:
https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77

So you're trying to do something like this with the nesting:

```
getConditionalDataUsingPromise() {
    this.httpClient.get<Employee>(this.url).toPromise().then(data => {
      console.log('First Promise resolved.')
      if (data.id > 5) {
        let anotherUrl = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/23';
        this.httpClient.get<Employee>(anotherUrl).toPromise().then(data => {
          this.conditionalPromiseResult = data;
          console.log('Second Promise resolved.')
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

You'll want to rewrite it like this:

```
async getConditionalDataUsingAsync() {
    let data = await this.httpClient.get<Employee>(this.url).toPromise();
    if (data.id > 5) {
      let anotherUrl = 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/23';
      this.conditionalAsyncResult = await this.httpClient.get<Employee>(anotherUrl).toPromise();
    }
    console.log('No issues, I will wait until promise is resolved..');
  }
```

Comment: I believe so. I am aware of this async await pattern in c#. looks like this is the one i would need. thanks.

Comment: No @blogs4t, that's not the way to go. There's no reason to convert an observable to a promise here.